# Disable auto snapping

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

i have a next question:

In Windows 8 when i tried to launch my other app from another app - there was no snapping by default, 1 application went to background and other went to front.

In windows 8.1 the application that lauched an URI goes to filled mode, but launchable app goes to snap - how to prevent this, and make it work like in Windows 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx) that you use to invoke the second app accepts a [LauncherOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.aspx) parameter. Use the [DesiredRemainingView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.desiredremainingview.aspx) property to control the launch with regards to size.

By default it's the app that launches another app that controls how the view will be shared. It might be possible to override this behavior. Windows grants apps the option to enlarge themselves when requiring more space. It might be possible to invoke this method to enlarge a launched app.